# Why is my draggable component in React moving ahead of cursor onmousemove?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, draggable, drag

This is my first Stack Overflow question, so please be patient with me and let me know if you need additional information! I'm essentially re-creating a simplified Beyond20 interactable map for Dungeon Master's to use. Building up a project portfolio for first time junior dev apps.

Anyway, I've made moveable "pieces" out of solid background-color divs with short text names that can be moved around a map image on the board. Rather than import a prebuilt library like React DnD, I wanted to do this from scratch to get a better sense of the mechanics. I store my moving logic in the component Draggable (below). Whenever I drag a "piece," however, the piece gradually moves AHEAD of the cursor (note: it does NOT lag behind like I've read about elsewhere, it slowly glides ahead in whatever direction the cursor travels), and this behavior happens on EVERY monitor screen I've tested it on except the original monitor I wrote the code on. To note as well, the draggable component travels a replicable distance from the cursor on any drag event, meaning that, if I drag my element, say, 300px, it will always end up the same distance ahead of my cursor.

I hope this makes sense. Please let me know if I can clarify anything. Any and all advice is so deeply appreciated!

Draggable component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';


function Draggable({ 
  children, 
  position, 
  updatePosition, 
  deleteIcon, 
  id
 }) {
  const [drop, setDrop] = useState({ x: position.x, y: position.y })
  const dragRef = useRef()

  const handlePointerDown = (e) => {
    window.addEventListener('pointermove', handleDragMove);
    window.addEventListener('pointerup', handlePointerUp);
  };
  
  const handleDragMove = (e) => {
      dragRef.current.style.left = `${dragRef.current.offsetLeft + e.movementX}px`
      dragRef.current.style.top = `${dragRef.current.offsetTop + e.movementY}px`
  };

  const handlePointerUp = (e) => {

    const aspectBox = document.getElementById('aspectRatioBox')
    const bounding = dragRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();

    if(bounding.x < 100 && bounding.y < 100) {
      //Below conditional is for deleting an Icon if dropped within a specific area on page

      try {
        deleteIcon(id)
      } catch(exception) {
        console.log('Unable to delete icon', exception)
      }
    } else if (drop.x !== dragRef.current.style.left && drop.y !== dragRef.current.style.top) {  
      //This is for updating the position in the server through socket.io and saving to database

      setDrop({
        x: `${dragRef.current.style.left.replace(/px/g, '')/aspectBox.clientWidth*100}%`,
        y: `${dragRef.current.style.top.replace(/px/g, '')/aspectBox.clientHeight*100}%`
      })
    }
    window.removeEventListener('pointermove', handleDragMove);
    window.removeEventListener('pointerup', handlePointerUp);
  }



  const preventBehavior =(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('touchmove', preventBehavior, {passive: false})

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('pointerup', handlePointerUp)
      window.removeEventListener('touchmove', preventBehavior, {passive: false})
      window.removeEventListener('pointermove', handleDragMove);
      window.removeEventListener('pointerup', handlePointerUp);
    } 

  }, [])


  const firstRender = useRef(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!firstRender.current) {
      updatePosition({ 
        x: drop.x, 
        y: drop.y 
      }, id)
    }
  }, [drop.x, drop.y] ) 

  useEffect(() => { firstRender.current = false }, [])
  return (
    <div
      onPointerDown={handlePointerDown}
      style={{top: position.y, left: position.x}}
      className="draggableBox"
      ref={dragRef}
    >
      {children}
    </div>

  )
}

export default Draggable
```

Answer (score 2):

So I found a solid work-around to my issue after many, many hours of failed Google Foo.

I don't believe this solves whatever my root issue was with the draggable element getting ahead of the cursor, but I believe it had something to do with the additive nature of my position updating through e.movementX and e.movementY.

```
const handlePointerDown = (e) => {

  const { left, top }  = dragRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
  posRef.current = {
    x: left - e.clientX,
    y: top - e.clientY
  }

  
   window.addEventListener('pointermove', handleDragMove);
   window.addEventListener('pointerup', handlePointerUp);

   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
};
  

const handleDragMove = (e) => {
  const aspectBox = document.getElementById('aspectRatioBox').getBoundingClientRect()

  dragRef.current.style.left = `${(e.clientX + posRef.current.x - aspectBox.left)/aspectBox.width*100}%`
  dragRef.current.style.top = `${(e.clientY + posRef.current.y - aspectBox.top)/aspectBox.height*100}%`
 
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();


};
```

I get the relative position of the draggable element through the delta of the box within which it moves and the cursor's e.Client position. I've added to this a ref **posRef** that allows for more precise movement of the icon, rather than instantly snapping the cursor to the top left of the icon.

Hope this helps anyone who finds themselves in a similar situation!!!